# JUnit 5 report to json or test runner with json reporting

Tags: json, xml, junit, junit5, jira-xray

I have a test documentation tool which accepts reports in XML and JSON. I need to attach screenshots to every test case even the passed ones. Unfortunately, the tool (xRay for Jira) can only digest screenshots in a form of JSON and cannot in XML.
I know that cucumber does reports in json but I do not want tests to be BDD-like.

**Is there a test runner, which can do reporting in JSON or a solution on how to convert JUnit 5 XML report to appropriate [JSON format](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results#:%7E:text=Xray%20JSON%20format,-Xray%20also%20supports&text=This%20allows%20you%20to%20import,from%20automated%20or%20manual%20Tests.&text=This%20format%20supports%20importing%20execution,file%20encoded%20in%20Base%2064.) with screenshots in Base64.**

Current set up is Java/Gradle/JUnit5/Selenide but can be reviewed.

Comment: You can implement your own reporter that generates the output in json. You'll have to wrestle a bit with your build system to get it activated: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing attachments, as of today, is supported if you use Xray JSON or Cucumber JSON reports.

The only way, right now, would be to implement either a JUnit5 TestExecutionListener or a TestWatcher that would generate a Xray JSON report.

Note: in the short term, support will be added for [JUnit 5](https://github.com/bitcoder/xray-junit-extensions) and also for [TestNG](https://github.com/bitcoder/xray-testng-extensions); currently, this is experimental and not yet supported in the product *but* please raise a [support request](https://jira.xpand-it.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) asking for this improvement, so the team can track your interest on it. The URLs for the previous repos will probably change.